# Read Index RGB File and convert to Grey Scale Image - What is double, thinning and Inverted Images Format

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to read GIF file and display in below following format -

```
Grey Scale
Resized 
Double Image
Thinning
Inverted
```

Below is my code to do the same (incomplete):

```
clear all;
close all;
clc;

%Various preprocessing of Images
checkimage=imread('CheckSign/sign.gif');
checkimage_resize=imresize(checkimage,[512, 512]);
checkimage_grey=rgb2gray(checkimage_resize);
[m n p] = size(checkimage_grey)
for i=1:n
    for j=1:m
        if(checkimage_grey(i,j) ~= 0)
            bimage(i,j) = 1;
        else
            bimage(i,j) = 0;
        end
    end
end
subplot (2,3,1),imshow(checkimage),title('Original Image');
subplot (2,3,2),imshow(checkimage_resize),title('Resized Image');
subplot (2,3,3),imshow(checkimage_grey),title('Grey Scale Image');
subplot (2,3,4),imshow(bimage),title('Binary Image');
```

But I get the below error:

```
Error using rgb2gray>parse_inputs (line 81)
MAP must be a m x 3 array.

Error in rgb2gray (line 35)
X = parse_inputs(varargin{:});

Error in preprocessing (line 8)
checkimage_grey=rgb2gray(checkimage_resize);
```

On viewing the image in imtool I see a pixel info as:

```
Pixel (X,Y) index [R,G,B]

<213>
R 0.80 
G 0.80 
B 1.00
```

Now I am not sure how to read this kind of index file and convert to grey scale one?

Also how do I change the image in concern to double, thinning and Inverted Imagesformat?

If I not wrong is **inverted** image as **1 - bimage**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For indexed images you need to read the index as well as the colorap

```
[ind map] = imread( 'CheckSign/sign.gif' );
```

Once you have all the information you need you can use [`ind2rgb`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2rgb.html) to convert the index map into RGB image

```
checkimage_rgb = ind2rgb( ind, map );
```

You do not need a nested `for`-loop to "invert" the colors, it's enough

```
bimage = checkimage_grey ~= 0;
inverted = 1 - bimage;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works - Can you please let me know how we can create the double and thinning image out of the main image?

Comment: @Prakash look at [`im2double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2double.html) and [`bwmorph`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html) for more information.